# Spyder sys.argv error: NameError: name 'basestring' is not defined

Tags: python, spyder, argv

UPDATE (2022-03-02): I discovered another nasty error. The Spyder IDE debugger doesn't work either. :-( The error is another namespace error (similar, but different from the error below). I'm beginning to think I have a conflict from a package I installed last week.

```
TypeError: runfile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'current_namespace'
```

I have used Spyder IDE for several years without problems. Today I experienced an error with `sys.argv` usage in the IDE (only). (This is in a script I have run several times a month over the past year.) I am trying to diagnose how/why this popped up. I have not changed my Spyder installation (at least not intentionally). I recently installed the cartopy package and installed/removed basemap package. Spyder configuration:

```
E:\kcw78> list spyder
# packages in environment at C:\anaconda\Miniconda3:
# Name                    Version                   Build
pyls-spyder               0.3.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
spyder                    4.2.0            py38haa95532_0
spyder-kernels            1.10.2           py38haa95532_0
```

Simple test code:

```
import sys
print(len(sys.argv))
print(sys.argv)
```

Behavior:
The script runs as expected when I execute it in a command window (w/ or w/out arguments).
Output below:

```
E:\kcw78> python test_sysargv.py
1
['test_sysargv.py']

E:\kcw78> python test_sysargv.py testval
2
['test_sysargv.py', 'testval']
```

I get different behavior when I run in the Spyder IDE.
It works if I don't enter any command line options (under Run/Configuration per file).
However, I get an error when I enter a value in Command line options. Error message in IPython console window:

```
runfile('E:/kcw78/test_sysargv.py', args='name.txt', wdir='E:/kcw78')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Windows\TEMP/ipykernel_5888/3729903912.py", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('E:/kcw78/test_sysargv.py', args='name.txt', wdir='E:/kcw78')

  File "C:\anaconda\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 147, in runfile
    if args is not None and not isinstance(args, basestring):

NameError: name 'basestring' is not defined
```

Any suggestions why I get different behavior for execution in Spyder vs command line? For example, configuration settings to check?

Comment: You appear to be trying to use a Python 2.x module on a Python 3.x interpreter - `basestring` was removed from the language in 3.0.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting clue. This environment is Python 3.8 (never installed Python 2.x on this computer AFAIK). Could 1 of the packages I installed include a Python 2.x module? (Spyder has been weird since I did that last week -- this is the biggest problem).

Comment: did you try `pip3 install basestring`   ?

Comment: No, I didn't know `basestring` was a module. I use 2 workarounds. I have a Python 3.6 environment that still works, and run it when I have to need `sys.argv` or to run the debugger. Other times, I just hard code `sys.argv` values in the IDE, then remove and test from the command line. Yes, painful, but it works.